# Issue with json_decode and json_encode - it adds keys to original JSON

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON string:

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "producta",
            "size": "50",
            "weight": "1000",
            "price": "30",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "producta",
            "size": "50",
            "weight": "1000",
            "price": "30",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I use the PHP function **json_decode($products, true)**, and then I re-encode it using **json_encode($products)**, the string becomes this:

```
{
    "product": {
        "1": {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "producta",
            "size": "50",
            "weight": "1000",
            "price": "30",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "2"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "producta",
            "size": "50",
            "weight": "1000",
            "price": "30",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "3"
        }
    }
}
```

After decoding and re-encoding, it adds a key to every "product"

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Holy bleepity bleep Batman! That's horrible!

Comment: :/ Is there a mistake in the way that it is originally formatted?

Comment: @TaylorMac: No, it's just a new way for me to hate PHP.

Comment: @RPM: "Usually you retrieve JSON data with JavaScript" Really? I usually use Python to pull it from web services.

Comment: Well the shopping cart on my website stores the cart items in JSON format (as shown above). The purpose of the encode and decode functions in PHP is to handle data like this received from client side  processing.

Comment: All PHP arrays **MUST** have keys. json_encode() will do an exact reproduction of whatever's stored internally, and that includes those keys.

Comment: @Marc: But then why wouldn't it just decode with an initial key of 0 in the first place, meaning that it wouldn't need to convert it from an array into an object? HATE HATE HATE...

Comment: Well then that is fine... but how do I convert it back?

Comment: Sorry for just asking for an answer I have just been frustrated with this for hours

Comment: @Ignacio: I can't reproduce the OP's stuff even after cutting/pasting the sample string and doing `echo json_encode(json_decode($j, true))`. I don't get the extra key stuff, on php 5.3.6

Comment: I face the same issue, when I swipe array_keys with my array_search - key values and getting 0, 1 etc key values with my resulting json_encoded array. Any suggestions pls? My question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228468/php-array-search-appends-keys-with-json-encode-function-parsing-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this here since it'd be too ugly in a comment, but this is what I get on PHP 5.3.6 after doing a `echo json_encode(json_decode('...your json...', true));`:

```
{"product":  [
     {"id":"1","title":"producta","size":"50","weight":"1000","price":"30","quantity":"100","cartID":"1"},
     {"id":"1","title":"producta","size":"50","weight":"1000","price":"30","quantity":"100","cartID":"2"}
]}
```

Note the lack of extra keys. Are you doing any manipulations on the decoed array before re-encoding?

Comment: I'm glad it is working for you. I am not making any manipulations... it may be the PHP version :/

Comment: I face the same issue, when I swipe array_keys with my array_search - key values and getting 0, 1 etc key values with my resulting json_encoded array. Any suggestions pls? My question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228468/php-array-search-appends-keys-with-json-encode-function-parsing-issue

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using mysqli_fetch_array instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc. Meaning u are json decoding a key arreay instead of an associative array